# nullPointerException if add ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

here's my code

```
public class Income extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private String[] tabs = { "My Income", "Add Income" };
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.income,container, false);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.vpIncome);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {

                case 0: return new IncomeList();
                case 1: return new IncomeAdd();
                //case 2: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
                default: return new IncomeList();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

the app would run without any problem without this code above

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
```

the app could run, i could select the class Income from navigation drawer and perform swipe between IncomeList and IncomeAdd. But when I add the code above (which I need, since I need the tabs), the app would throw NullPointerException

forgot to add the (almost) full error message was:
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.code.imin.mymoneymanaged.Income.onTabSelected(Income.java:86)

here's my NavigationDrawer which will call the Income class code:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Fragment used for managing interactions for and presentation of a navigation drawer.
 * See the <a href="https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction">
 * design guidelines</a> for a complete explanation of the behaviors implemented here.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
     * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
     */
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Retain this fragment across configuration changes - added to make sure data in fragment retains after orientation changes
        setRetainInstance(true);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.menu_dashboard),
                        getString(R.string.menu_expenses),
                        getString(R.string.menu_income),
                        getString(R.string.menu_moneyjar),
                        getString(R.string.menu_goal),
                        getString(R.string.menu_report),
                        getString(R.string.menu_settings),
                }));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }

        Fragment fragment = null;
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Dashboard();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentDashboard");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Expenses();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentExpenses");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Income();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentIncome");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new MoneyJar();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentMoneyJar");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new Goal();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentGoal");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new Report();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentReport");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                break;
            case 6:
                fragment = new Settings();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentSettings");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
            Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
            today.setToNow();

            int selectedDay = Integer.parseInt(today.format("%d"));
            int selectedMonth = Integer.parseInt(today.format("%m")) - 1;
            int selectedYear = Integer.parseInt(today.format("%Y"));
            ExpensesAdd dfExpensesAdd = ExpensesAdd.newInstance(selectedYear,selectedMonth,selectedDay);
            dfExpensesAdd.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),"fragmentDialog");
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
     * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: @shayanpourvatan, i have this on my NavigationDrawerFragment.java which is used to open the Income class "private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }"

Answer (score 1):

viewPager is null in your code, you define inner viewPager object in `onCreateView`

```
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.income,container, false);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.vpIncome);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
```

but you have try to access class ViewPager object that you not initialize that:

```
    private ViewPager viewPager;
```

and you use this object in `onTabSelected`

```
 @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }
```

for solving this issue use Class ViewPager in onCreateView, use following code

```
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.income,container, false);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.vpIncome);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
```

Comment: I've done what you asked, but it still returns the same error, and it still points to the same thing, which is "java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.code.imin.mymoneymanaged.Income.onTabSelected"

Comment: can you post new code, and indicate line 78 @ `Income.java`

Comment: clean and build project and run again, because only possible thing is that `viewPager` is null, if your problem not be solved with clean try move initializing code to `onViewCreate` and try again

Comment: the error still appear. if I tried to comment out the line viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());, the error won't appear, and the app will display the tabs for a second but the tabs will disappear after that. swipe will still work. i tried to move the initializing code to onCreateView and the same thing will happen; the apps won't crash, but the tabs will only appear for a second.

Comment: fyi, my apps implement navigation drawer that has ActionBarDrawerToggle inside it. I've copy pasted my navigationdrawer code, if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your code to get the actionBar to the onActivityCreated method and see if that works.

Comment: the same thing happened; the tabs appear only for less than a second